# Switching between multiple AC sources with combined neutrals but separate, independent input loads to common outlet load

Tags: wiring

OK, what I have is 4 different AC sources only one of which is connected (switched) to the outlets at a time. What problem can I expect if I combine all neutrals for all sources and outlets, combine all grounds from all sources, but only switch in one load at a time. In other words, I will switch EACH of the AC sources so that only ONE load travels to the outlets and does not come in contact with the other load wires. In structured format, I have a four separate load wires coming from four separate 120v AC inputs, they travel through independent multipole switch to go to a single load wire running to the outlets. Only one is possible load to travel through the switch at a time. Will the combined neutrals somehow create some unusual path of return for the current?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. Please add a diagram.

Comment: That would depend on what those AC sources are. We don't know what sources you have and how they connect their neutrals in respect to ground/earth, if it is a generator or inverter, so we can't say what happens unless you provide more info.

Comment: I cannot vouch for your system because I am not sure I understand it. But I can tell you that generally, automatic transfer switches for inverters and generators do NOT switch neutral or ground. They pass neutral and ground straight through. Only the two hot wires are switched. North American 240 V split phase has two hot wires. Sounds like you only have one hot wire, so you only need to switch that one wire. Of course the details of the switch and how the wiring is done etc will determine whether it is actually safe.

Comment: I am asking about the impact of AC when the load is switched in one at a time while combining neutrals. No idea how to make it simpler.  I have (500) 120VAC circuits where the load will connect only one at a time. I will combine all neutrals to both the (500) AC input circuits and (500) outlets. I will combine (all 1000) grounds. Will there be a path when I switch in 1 single 120VAC circuit to the 500 outlets that will create a problem.  EXAMPLE:  I have 100 line voltage from power company, 100 from inverters, 100 from generators, 100 from solar, etc.

Comment: mkeith you are on the track of what I am talking about.  I am guessing the ATS simply detects  Line AC and determines which load to send through, so all the neutrals combine and separately all the grounds combine.  Basically I only need to manually switch the load wires and I am asking if there will be no problem with some strange behavior of AC to travel in some kind of reverse direction through components.

Comment: Peter, maybe if you give some context to this question we can help you further as it's rather confused at present. Your question says you have four sources, your comment says (500). (Why are the numbers in brackets?) "*... so that only ONE load travels to the outlets ...*" Loads don't travel - current flows from the supply to the load. How do you have (all 1000) grounds? What does "*I have 100 line voltage ...*" mean? Are you saying you have a 100 V AC supply?

Comment: In electrical terminology, a "load" is typically the 'output device' which is consuming power, yet you seem to be using the term as if it's a power source ... ?

Comment: There are situations where NEC requires neutrals to be switched. That is related to source grounding and whether or not the alternate source is considered to be "separately derived." Utility approval is often required for transfer stitches that connect other sources to load that they also supply. There is also the possibility that the system design may need to be provided by a licensed engineer.

Comment: The only way there could be problems with the neutrals and grounds would be if there are strange interactions between the AC sources on your side of the switch. If the hot wires from all AC sources are isolated from each other it should be OK (unless I am not understanding correctly).

Answer (score 2):

It would be safer to switch the lines as well as the neutrals.

[image]

There would be only one common ground.

Comment: "It would be safer to switch the lines as well as the neutrals."  The reply did not answer the question.  I did not ask other ways to do it so this reply means nothing.  One of the other replies stated that all neutrals and grounds are connected in an AC auto switch, switching only the load wires.  That is the actual answer.  You can switch independent loads as long as only one is connected at a time.

Comment: Hi Peter, When you ask a question, not to accept the answer is your prerogative. Justification of the same is neither necessary nor expected.